# Derived classes containing lists of other subclasses

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have an abstract class with derived classes:

```
abstract class FoxObject : ICloneable
    {
        public int lineNumber;
        public string line, name;
        public FoxObject parent;
        public List<FoxObject> children;
        private Guid guid;

        protected FoxObject(int lineNumber, string line, string name, FoxObject parent, List<FoxObject> children)
        {
            this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
            this.line = line;
            this.name = name;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = children;
            guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

     //Code not relevant to this question.
    }
```

From which I have several derived classes (all inheriting directly from `FoxObject`: `Symbol`,`Graphic`,`Alias`,`Action` and `Update`.

Each `Graphic` contains a `List<Symbol>` each Symbol a List containing aliases, actions and updates (or three separate lists, this is part of the question). Currently however, these are all handled by the `List<FoxObject>` in the parent class such that there is a high level of polymorphism.

My question is, is there a way to indicate, in the derived classes what the `List<FoxObject>` actually contains to save having to cast it every time?

If not, would it make sense to just have these `List<T>`s with the same name but different `type`s and remove it from the `FoxObject` class?

Comment: Sounds like you should not derive from `FoxObject`. Obviously when an `Symbol` has different member than a `FoxObject`, they should not belong to the same inheritance-chain. Consider composition instead which means a `Symbol` *has three reference* to `FoxObject` instead - one for a `Graphics`,  one for an `Alias` and one for an `Action`.

Comment: does Symbol have 3 different lists ? Of Alias, Action and Update?

Comment: Is it so or do you want it so? I don´t know but from what you´ve wrote a `Symbol` shpuld have a reference to another `FoxObject` instead as `FoxObject` doesn´t know anything of a `List<Alias>` for example, however `Symbol` does.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin it could do, or the `List<FoxObject>` children` could contain all three of those. That's part of the question (possibly didn't ask clearly enough).

Comment: But you wrote a `Symbol` has three lists instead of one.

Comment: @HimBromBeere a `Symbol` is a `FoxObject` as far as I am concerned. I'm writing these classes such that each class represents one of the objects on a graphic file (that is getting processed). The graphic file contains symbols, aliases, updates, actions etc. all of which should be considered `FoxObjects` but also need some separate members and functions. Hence the derivation structure. The question of whether or not a symbol should have a `List<FoxObject>` or three Lists is part of this.

Comment: what is with Parent property  ? What are parents of all these classes?

Comment: You can always use `new` keyword to override field in different derived objects : `Graphic` -> `public new List<Symbol> children`

Comment: @MaksimSimkin the `Parent` of an instance of a `Symbol` would be the graphic that it is on, an `Alias` the `Symbol` that it is in etc

Comment: @m.rogalski would this be considered bad practice or is it pretty standard?

Comment: and Parent of the Graphic?

Comment: @JamesHughes I don't know. If it works and works good then why should it be a "bad practice"?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin, a `Graphic` would just leave this as `null`

Comment: @m.rogalski good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer would be to just make use of the `new` keyword and just override member field of base class :

```
// no changes with the base class
abstract class FoxObject : ICloneable
{
    public int lineNumber;
    public string line, name;
    public FoxObject parent;
    public List<FoxObject> children;
    private Guid guid;

    protected FoxObject(int lineNumber, string line, string name, FoxObject parent, List<FoxObject> children)
    {
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
        this.line = line;
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = children;
        guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

 //Code not relevant to this question.
}

// example Graphic object
class Graphic : FoxObject
{
    public new List<Symbol> children; // like this.
}
```

Comment: New does not override, it shadows the member. If you do `FoxObject a = new Graphic(...)` doing `a.children` will give you the base list, not the list inside of `Graphic`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It "shadows" ? I know that it will generate "new method" only for the derived object ( like everyone else knows ) you should really read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Comment: The term shadowing is a older term [that comes from visual basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4swkw24.aspx) however it is frequently used in C# to mean the same thing.

Comment: I've decided to do away with the inheritance because it is arguably of little value in this instance, I might add an interface later for a few little methods that they all need to implement. Either way, this answer seems like it answers my question the best so I'm marking it as accepted.